# How to rename multiple files by replacing word in file name?

Tags: shell, files, rename, sed

Replace ACDC to AC-DC

For example we have these files

> ACDC - Rock N' Roll Ain't Noise Pollution.xxx
>
> ACDC - Rocker.xxx
>
> ACDC - Shoot To Thrill.xxx

I want them to become:

> AC-DC - Rock N' Roll Ain't Noise Pollution.xxx
>
> AC-DC - Rocker.xxx
>
> AC-DC - Shoot To Thrill.xxx

I know that sed or awk is used for this operation. I can't google anything so I'm asking for your help =) Could you please provide full working shell command for this task?

Feedback: [Solution for OSX users](https://superuser.com/questions/152627/renaming-many-files-in-mac-os-x-batch-processing)

Comment: I sense there is a larger question here - are you trying to fix up mp3 filenames in general?  There are a number of scripts people have written over the years to do this.  I think one I've used was called `mp3fixer`.

Comment: no it's not about mp3's I just have to manage some huge files with similar names, and something everything must be replaced or fixed...  common situation so I need this nifty solution for renaming all of them

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
rename 's/ACDC/AC-DC/' *.xxx
```

from `man rename`

```
DESCRIPTION
       "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as the 
first argument.  The perlexpr argument is a Perl expression which is expected to modify the 
$_ string in Perl for at least some of the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not 
modified by the expression, it will not be renamed.  If no filenames are given on
           the command line, filenames will be read via standard input.
```

For example, to rename all files matching "*.bak" to strip the extension, you might say

```
rename 's/\.bak$//' *.bak
```

To translate uppercase names to lower, you'd use

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

Comment: Note that many linux machines come with rename from util-linux, which implements simple substitution, *not* regexes.  So if rename fails silently without doing anything, you're probably using the wrong `rename`.

Comment: @PhilHollenback How to find/install the right one then? :)

Comment: It doesn't work when I have underscores in my filenames instead of spaces - how can I solve that?

Comment: @henry it's called perl-rename in some distribution

Answer (score 16):

*This answer contains the good parts from all other answers, while leaving out such heresy as `ls | while read`.*

Current directory:

```
for file in ACDC*.xxx; do
    mv "$file" "${file//ACDC/AC-DC}"
done
```

Including subdirectories:

```
find . -type f -name "ACDC*" -print0 | while read -r -d '' file; do
    mv "$file" "${file//ACDC/AC-DC}"
done
```

Newline characters are *really* unlikely to be in filenames, so this can be simpler while still working with names containing spaces:

```
find . -type f -name "ACDC*" | while read -r file; do
    mv "$file" "${file//ACDC/AC-DC}"
done
```

Answer (score 14):

To use the util-linux version of `rename` that Phil referred to (on Ubuntu, it's called `rename.ul`):

```
rename ACDC AC-DC ACDC*
```

or

```
rename.ul ACDC AC-DC ACDC*
```

Comment: your variant is the best =) so many stupid articles in google about find and send and awk... to this simple operation for which renameutils egxist already!

Comment: Quick and easy. Unforgettable!

Answer (score 4):

Using the bash shell

```
find . -type f -name "ACDC*" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f
do
   new=`echo "$f" | sed -e "s/ACDC/AC-DC/"`
   mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

Note: using `find` will process the current directory, and the directories under.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your shell. In zsh, I'd do this:

```
for file in ACDC*.xxx; do
    mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed -e 's/ACDC/AC-DC/')"
done
```

Probably not the best solution, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Using bash:

```
ls *.xxx | while read fn; do
    mv "${fn}" "${fn/ACDC/AC-DC}";
done
```

If you have the `rename` program installed:

```
rename 's/ACDC/AC-DC/' *.xxx
```